# Woocommerce: How to convert product reviews in carousel/slider?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, carousel

I'm working on a woocommerce store. I want to convert standard list styled reviews into carousel/slider. Something like this with star-rating at top. 
[image]

What must I do to achieve this? I'm using Flatsome theme.

Answer (score 0):

Okay First you need to customize single-product-reviews.php file,
Copy the file to a directory within your theme or child theme named woocommerce and add a class to wrap commentlist element in order to use it with any slider library such as owl-carousel.
then you can target the newly class to create the carousel
here a code where I customized the file by adding owl-carousel class to initialize owl-carousel

```js
// reviews slider
    $('#comments .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        //stagePadding: 50,
        loop:true,
        margin:20,
        nav:true,
        items: 1,
        navText: [
            "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>",
            "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"
        ],
        responsive: {
            767: {
                items:2,
            },
        },
        dots:false,
    });
```

```html
<?php
/**
 * Display single product reviews (comments)
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product-reviews.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see      https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author   WooThemes
 * @package  WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.5.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

if ( ! comments_open() ) {
 return;
}

?>
<div id="reviews" class="woocommerce-Reviews">
 <div id="comments">
  <h2 class="woocommerce-Reviews-title"><?php
   if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' && ( $count = $product->get_review_count() ) ) {
    /* translators: 1: reviews count 2: product name */
    printf( esc_html( _n( '%1$s review for %2$s', '%1$s reviews for %2$s', $count, 'woocommerce' ) ), esc_html( $count ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
   } else {
    _e( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' );
   }
  ?></h2>

  <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

   <ol class="commentlist owl-carousel">
    <?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ) ); ?>
   </ol>

   <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
    echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
    paginate_comments_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args', array(
     'prev_text' => '&larr;',
     'next_text' => '&rarr;',
     'type'      => 'list',
    ) ) );
    echo '</nav>';
   endif; ?>

  <?php else : ?>

   <p class="woocommerce-noreviews"><?php _e( 'There are no reviews yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

  <?php endif; ?>
 </div>

 <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_review_rating_verification_required' ) === 'no' || wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) : ?>

  <div id="review_form_wrapper">
   <div id="review_form">
    <?php
     $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

     $comment_form = array(
      'title_reply'          => have_comments() ? __( 'Add a review', 'woocommerce' ) : sprintf( __( 'Be the first to review &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'woocommerce' ), get_the_title() ),
      'title_reply_to'       => __( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'woocommerce' ),
      'title_reply_before'   => '<span id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">',
      'title_reply_after'    => '</span>',
      'comment_notes_after'  => '',
      'fields'               => array(
       'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . esc_html__( 'Name', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label> ' .
          '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30" required /></p>',
       'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . esc_html__( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label> ' .
          '<input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30" required /></p>',
      ),
      'label_submit'  => __( 'Submit', 'woocommerce' ),
      'logged_in_as'  => '',
      'comment_field' => '',
     );

     if ( $account_page_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) {
      $comment_form['must_log_in'] = '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a review.', 'woocommerce' ), esc_url( $account_page_url ) ) . '</p>';
     }

     if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'yes' ) {
      $comment_form['comment_field'] = '<div class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating">' . esc_html__( 'Your rating', 'woocommerce' ) . '</label><select name="rating" id="rating" required>
       <option value="">' . esc_html__( 'Rate&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
       <option value="5">' . esc_html__( 'Perfect', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
       <option value="4">' . esc_html__( 'Good', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
       <option value="3">' . esc_html__( 'Average', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
       <option value="2">' . esc_html__( 'Not that bad', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
       <option value="1">' . esc_html__( 'Very poor', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
      </select></div>';
     }

     $comment_form['comment_field'] .= '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . esc_html__( 'Your review', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" required></textarea></p>';

     comment_form( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args', $comment_form ) );
    ?>
   </div>
  </div>

 <?php else : ?>

  <p class="woocommerce-verification-required"><?php _e( 'Only logged in customers who have purchased this product may leave a review.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

 <?php endif; ?>

 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

if you need help with owl-carousel let me know